Getting different nullable reference types results between LINQ query syntax and the equivalent method syntax
I'm using Visual Studio 2022 (with ReSharper 2024.1 but I don't think that's relevant) developing in .NET 8. My minimal repro is this:
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string? ANullableString()
        {
            return Random.Shared.Next(10) % 2 == 0 ? null : "Panda";
        }

        var querySyntax =
            (from i in Enumerable.Range(1, 4) 
             select (ANullableString(), ANullableString()))
            .First();

        var methodSyntax =
            (Enumerable.Range(1, 4)
             .Select(i => (ANullableString(), ANullableString())))
            .First();

        // No warnings
        var querySyntaxItem1Length = querySyntax.Item1.Length;
        
        // Warning CS8602
        var methodSyntaxItem1Length = methodSyntax.Item1.Length;
    }
}

My understanding of LINQ query-syntax style (from ... select) has always been that it is simply 'syntactic sugar' for the actual method calls. I asked ReSharper to convert the first to the second; but I agree with what it's done. Both lines, I thought, would do exactly the same thing. Therefore, I would expect querySyntax and methodSyntax to have the same inferred nullability analysis.
But they don't.
The compiler identifies querySyntax as a (string, string) , whereas methodSyntax is identified as a (string?, string?). This means that the indicated line gets compiler warning CS8602 "Dereference of a possibly null reference", but the equivalent line for querySyntax passed without warning. Naturally, both are equally likely to fail at execution time.
What am I missing? Is this: an error in my expectation about the equivalence of query syntax and method syntax; a limitation of the compiler's static nullability analysis; or something else?

I note that Claude told me "When using query syntax, the C# compiler often applies more optimistic type inference. It tends to infer non-nullable types unless it has strong evidence that the values could be null. This behavior is partly historical, predating the introduction of nullable reference types" but it's, you know, not always reliable...

Can you reproduce this using dotnetfiddle ? (My attempt at https://dotnetfiddle.net/JUo649 works as expected)

@sgmoore nice one. let me play around in there a bit

@sgmoore ok well I've already learned something - I didn't actually understand nullable reference types. Per the docs, they are actually the same runtime Types; all this nullable stuff is compile-time static analysis, which provides me with a clue as to what's happening here.

@sgmoore GetType() doesn’t tell you what the compiler is thinking, since the runtime representation is the same. Try printing err.Item1.Length and wut.Item1.Length. There will be a warning for the latter, but no warnings for the former.

@Sweeper I've literally just got to the exact same place myself :) Going to update the question

for null ref exception - make code safe methodSyntax.Item1?.Length; and for another one
